# How to pass ASP.NET user and route data to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some data about user and route in ASP.NET.
How to make it available in JavaScript?

Currently, I have the following line in `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("ContextScript", "WebParts"); }
```

`ContextScript` is an action which returns the following partial view:

```
<script id="context-script">
    var context = {
        controller: "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]",
        action: "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]",
        area: "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["area"]",
        culture: "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"]",
        isMobile: @Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice.ToString().ToLower(),
        rootUrl: "@BaseMulticultureHttpApplication.RootApplicationUrl",
        isAuthenticated: @User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString().ToLower(),
        username: "@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.Name : "")",
        isBankClient: @(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.AcquireUser().BankClientID.HasValue.ToString().ToLower() : "false"),
        iin: "@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.AcquireUser().IIN : "")",
        fullname: "@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.AcquireUser().FullName : "")"
    };
</script>
```

Then, this `context` is being read by a number of bundled scripts.

However, I strongly believe that there is a better option since:

- User and route information is available in a global scope, polluting it and making this `context` available to malicious browsers plugins, XSS-injected scripts (who knows) etc.
- Some information about implementation is disclosed to an end-user

What is a correct and safe way to do this?

Comment: I don't know if it bad practice or not. But it seems that Instagram doing it the same way. http://i.imgur.com/WNH4B3h.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my own unanswered question from the perspective of two more years of experience, I would say that using AJAX is probably the most appropriate solution:

That is RouteData can be injected as it is:

```
<script id="context-script">
    var context = {
        controller: "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]",
        action: "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]",
        area: "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["area"]",
        culture: "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"]",
        isMobile: @Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice.ToString().ToLower()
    };
</script>
```

But user data should be exposed as API:

```
// ASP.NET -> Models
public class CurrentUserModel
{
    public CurrentUserModel(...) 
    {
        // initialize properties
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; }

    public string Username { get; }

    // other properties go here
}

// ASP.NET -> Controllers
public class UserController : ApiController 
{
    // GET /user/current
    [HttpGet] 
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<CurrentUserModel> Current()
    {
        CurrentUserModel model = new CurrentUserModel(...);
        return Ok(model);            
    }
}

// Client-side
<script>
    apiClient.user.current().then(u => {
        // work with user details here
    });
</script>
```

GET action is used here just as a REST-style example. Additional security considerations are required. For example, if your API is hosted on the same domain and uses cookie for authentication, then consider applying AntiForgeryToken or switching to POST method to protect from CSRF attacks.